# How to Call List Map in Another Class with Iterator in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I have calling items of spinner using list map. Firstly, I have success to calling list map with `ITERATOR` in same class. Then, I have modify my program by replacing previous my list Map in another class and calling it with `ITERATOR`, but result appearing error in Iterator.

MY CODE is :

1. SUCCESS in same class

(Class get items)

```
for (String city in _cities) {
      // here I am calling the drop down menu 
      // items
 }

List _cities =
     ["Cluj-Napoca",
     "Bucuresti",
     "Timisoara", 
     "Brasov", 
     "Constanta"];
```

2. ERROR when I replacing List _cities in another class

(Class get items)

```
for (String city in _cities) {
    // here I am calling the drop down menu 
    // items
 }
```

(Class items)

```
List _cities =
    ["Cluj-Napoca",
    "Bucuresti",
    "Timisoara", 
    "Brasov", 
    "Constanta"];
```

Comment: What's the error you are receiving? Showing your code in context might be more helpful cuz the code blocks look identical. Are you trying to share a variable between 2 different classes or something?

Comment: Yes sir. I am trying to put variable List _cities in different class then passing them using Iterator "for", but show error in "Iterator". Please help me how to call variable List _cities inside Iterator in different class? Thx sir.